# raw postgresql query in django

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, rawsql

Please help me with raw postgresql query:

given `models.py`:

```
from django.db import models


class Menu(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    menu_url = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class MenuEntry(models.Model):
    menu = models.ForeignKey("menu", null=True, blank=True,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    parent = models.ForeignKey("menuentry", null=True,
                               blank=True,
                               on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.text
```

I am trying to retrieve a menu item with related tree of menuentries, in another `file`:

```
    queryset = MenuEntry.objects.raw("WITH RECURSIVE \
my_2ndmenu_items (id, parent, text) \
AS( \
SELECT * FROM menu_menuentry WHERE menu_menuentry.menu_id=(SELECT id FROM menu_menu WHERE name=%s) \
UNION \
SELECT m.* FROM menu_menuentry m \
INNER JOIN my_2ndmenu_items r ON m.parent_id = r.id \
WHERE m.parent_id IS NOT NULL \
) \
SELECT * FROM my_2ndmenu_items", ["menu_B"])
```

But I'm getting the following error, trying to get `queryset[0]`:

```
*** ValueError: Cannot assign "'menu_B_1lvl_entry'": "MenuEntry.parent" must be a "MenuEntry" instance.
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Changing this part of your raw query `my_2ndmenu_items (id, parent, text) \` to `my_2ndmenu_items (id, parent_id, text) \` should fix your problem.
But I'd also recommend making sure **name** on the `Menu` model is unique or you should change your subquery on `Menu` to something like this `SELECT * FROM menu_menuentry WHERE menu_menuentry.menu_id in (SELECT id FROM menu_menu WHERE name=%s) \`  in case you have more than one menu that matches the name you are searching for.

Answer (score 0):

the final answer is:

```
    queryset = MenuEntry.objects.raw("WITH RECURSIVE \
my_2ndmenu_items \
AS( \
SELECT * FROM menu_menuentry WHERE menu_menuentry.menu_id=(SELECT id FROM menu_menu WHERE name=%s) \
UNION \
SELECT m.* FROM menu_menuentry m \
INNER JOIN my_2ndmenu_items r ON m.parent_id = r.id \
WHERE m.parent_id IS NOT NULL \
) \
SELECT * FROM my_2ndmenu_items", ["menu_B"])
```

it seems to give what I want
thank you everyone for your help!